# ASP.NET Output Cache not working on IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7.5, webforms

I'm using the output cache feature for a page on my ASP.NET 3.5 website and it works fine on my local machine (Win XP / IIS5.1) but it won't cache when running on the development server (IIS7.5).

The code I'm using is below...

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" Location="Server" VaryByParam="*" %>
```

*Does anyone know how to get output caching to work on IIS7.5?*  I've searched through StackOverflow and Google and can't find anyone that's having similar issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim.

Comment: Are you sure the caching module is installed? Depending on how you installed IIS, not all of the modules are installed by default. If so and you need to install it, I suggest the Web Platform Installer from Microsoft. http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: Yes the caching module is installed (I can see it in IIS Manager).  I understand however that the page output cache is part of ASP.NET not IIS.  I'm using the Application Cache (System.Web.UI.Page.Cache) in other parts of my app and that seems to be running ok.  Really not sure why the output cache isn't working!  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please post relevant web.config settings, more context where the output cache is used, what you're using to determine if its caching or not, page profile output, .Net versions differences b/w dev and production environments, etc.

Comment: I think I've found the reason why the output cache isn't working.  I'm rewriting requests in the Application_BeginRequest function in global.asax.  If I disable the rewrites the output cache works.

Comment: I've also just switched my app from Integrated mode to Classic mode and now the output caching works as expected even when the url's are rewritten using the RewritePath method

Comment: It could be caused by different versions of the .NET Framework's support for cookies; check out here for my findings: * http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2012/10/aspnet-output-cache-not-working-and.html

Comment: [Does IIS 7.5 keep cache?](http://serverfault.com/questions/338860/does-iis-7-5-keep-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Are you rewriting the URL in global.asax ? It happens due to that.

OR

Have you tried switching Integrated mode to classic mode as Integrated mode overrides the settings which are working in IIS 6.0 and they are not working in IIS 7.5.